# Construct list of possible sentences from given alphabet quota and wordlist.txt

Tags: python, text, anagram

I have `wordlist.txt` that separated by new line.

If I specify number of quotas to use for each alphabet for example

```
n: 1
e: 1
w: 1
b: 1
o: 2
k: 1
Remain alphabets quota is 0.
```

How to construct a sentence from given quotas of alphabet that must be spent all until zero and based on words that defined in wordlist.txt?

For example, from given alphabet quotas, it will returning "new book" or "book new". Word order doesn't matter.

Where "new" and "book" has been exists in `wordlist.txt`.

So list of possible sentences might be like this:

```
new book
book new
bow neko
neko bow
```

Comment: Interesting problem! Off top of my head, I'd suggest using [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and check if any words in `wordlist.txt` match any permutation. Maybe a for loop to check the words in `wordlist.txt`. But this is me just brainstorming ideas, hopefully someone can help you with a more complete answer.

Comment: @IrfanZainudin Have you ever considered the time complexity of your proposed method?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi I did and it's not fast by any means but I was just suggesting off top of my head.

Comment: Many of your SO answers are to questions you submit yourself. Do you find this useful?

Comment: @user19077881 [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are few new words in `wordlist.txt` to handle multiple anagram:

```
bow
book
new
neko
ujang
wen
koob
```

if `book` and `koob` sorted, both will have same value, it's `bkoo`. The same value of words is considered as `anagram_id`.

Instead of using defined quota, I can just write the string directly that represent quota of alphabet, because when sorted, it will be same.

```
from itertools import combinations, product
from collections import OrderedDict

def generate_anagrams(input_sentence='k o bo ew n', wordlist_filepath='filtered_wordlist.txt'):
  input_sentence = filterOrigin(input_sentence)

  with open(wordlist_filepath, 'r') as file:
    wordlist = file.read().splitlines()

  anagram_id = []
  for word in wordlist:
    anagram_id.append(''.join(sorted(word))) # sorted word is anagram id

  sorted_input_sentence = ''.join(sorted(filterOrigin(input_sentence)))

  all_anagram_id = []
  for i in range(1, len(input_sentence)+1):
    combs = combinations(input_sentence, i)
    all_anagram_id += [''.join(sorted(comb)) for comb in combs]

  all_registered_anagram_id = []
  for id_from_input in all_anagram_id:
    for id_from_wordlist in anagram_id:
      if id_from_input == id_from_wordlist:
        all_registered_anagram_id.append(id_from_wordlist)

  all_registered_anagram_values = dict()
  for id in all_registered_anagram_id:
    all_registered_anagram_values[id] = ([wordlist[i] for i, x in enumerate(anagram_id) if x == id])

  sentence_combs = []
  for l in range(1, len(all_registered_anagram_id)+1):
    sentence_combs.append(set(combinations(all_registered_anagram_id, l)))

  valid_sentences_id = []
  for comb in sentence_combs:
    for pair in comb:
      candidate = ''.join(pair)
      if sorted_input_sentence == sorted(candidate): # is anagram?
        valid_sentences_id.append(pair)
  
  valid_sentences = []
  for sid in valid_sentences_id:
    broadcasted = []
    for id in sid:
      broadcasted.append(all_registered_anagram_values[id])
    for sentence in list(product(*broadcasted)):
      valid_sentences.append(' '.join(sentence))
  
  return valid_sentences

generate_anagrams()
```

Returning output:

```
['new book', 'new koob', 'wen book', 'wen koob', 'bow neko']
```